Navigation inside an AnimatedSize Dialog
Im trying to navigate inside a dialog and for that im using the Navigator Widget, and I got success with that code:
  const DocumentDialogPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DocumentDialogPage> createState() => _DocumentDialogPageState();
}

class _DocumentDialogPageState extends State<DocumentDialogPage> {
  final ValueNotifier<String> _titleNotifier =
      ValueNotifier<String>("Add Document");

  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _titleNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _updateTitle(String title) {
    _titleNotifier.value = title;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(56, 16.0, 56, 8.0),
      actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 24.0),
      title: ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
        valueListenable: _titleNotifier,
        builder: (context, title, child) {
          final canPop = _navigatorKey.currentState?.canPop() ?? false;
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              if (canPop)
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_navigatorKey.currentState!.canPop()) {
                      _updateTitle("Add Document");
                      _navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              if (!canPop) const SizedBox(width: 48),
              Text(title),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      content: IntrinsicWidth(
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Navigator(
            key: _navigatorKey,
            onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
              WidgetBuilder builder;
              switch (settings.name) {
                case '/add':
                  _updateTitle("Add Document");
                  builder = (BuildContext context) => const AddDocumentPage();
                  break;
                case '/submit':
                  _updateTitle("Submit Document");
                  builder = (BuildContext context) => SubmitDocumentPage(
                        onPop: () {
                          _updateTitle("Add Document");
                        },
                      );
                  break;
                default:
                  _updateTitle("Add Document");
                  builder = (BuildContext context) => const AddDocumentPage();
              }
              return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddDocumentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddDocumentPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddDocumentPage> createState() => _AddDocumentPageState();
}

class _AddDocumentPageState extends State<AddDocumentPage> {
  DocumentType? _selectedDocumentType;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        MultiDropdown<DocumentType>(
            items: DocumentType.values
                .map(
                  (docType) => DropdownItem(
                    value: docType,
                    label: docType.name,
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            onSelectionChange: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedDocumentType = value.first;
              });
            }),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/submit');
          },
          child: const Text("Go to Submit Document"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SubmitDocumentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubmitDocumentPage({super.key, this.onPop});
  final VoidCallback? onPop;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        const Text("Submit Document Content"),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            onPop?.call();
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: const Text("Back to Add Document"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

But I wanted to put a dropdown Widget inside AddDocumentPage, and when I clicked on it, I got this result:

I still wanted to get a animated size, to show the flow steps, like this image:
And I got the result I want when I remove the navigator and used that logic:
import 'package:cpr_verde_front_end/api/models/model_project.dart';
import 'package:cpr_verde_front_end/colors.dart';
import 'package:cpr_verde_front_end/extensions/widget_layout_extension.dart';
import 'package:cpr_verde_front_end/guards/auth_guard.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DocumentDialogPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DocumentDialogPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DocumentDialogPage> createState() => _DocumentDialogPageState();
}

class _DocumentDialogPageState extends State<DocumentDialogPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final ValueNotifier<String> _titleNotifier =
      ValueNotifier<String>("Adicionar Certificado");
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  void _updateTitle(String title) {
    _titleNotifier.value = title;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _titleNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 8),
      actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: ValueListenableBuilder<String>(
        valueListenable: _titleNotifier,
        builder: (context, title, child) {
          final canPop = _navigatorKey.currentState?.canPop() ?? false;
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              if (canPop)
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_navigatorKey.currentState!.canPop()) {
                      _updateTitle("Add Document");
                      _navigatorKey.currentState!.pop();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              if (!canPop) const SizedBox(width: 48),
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      content: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
        ),
        child: const IntrinsicWidth(
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: AddDocumentPage(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddDocumentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddDocumentPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddDocumentPage> createState() => _AddDocumentPageState();
}

class _AddDocumentPageState extends State<AddDocumentPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  DocumentType? _selectedDocumentType;
  final TextEditingController _dataController = TextEditingController();
  DateTime? _selectedDate;
  bool _fileUploaded = false;
  bool _dateSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSize(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Selecione abaixo o tipo de certificado.",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
          ).withPadding(
            const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 420,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: DropdownButton(
              value: _selectedDocumentType,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              hint: const Text("Selecione o tipo de documento"),
              isExpanded: true,
              items: DocumentType.values
                  .map(
                    (docType) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: docType,
                      child: Text(docType.name),
                    ),
                  )
                  .toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedDocumentType = value as DocumentType;
                  },
                );
              },
            ).withPadding(
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            ),
          ),
          // MultiDropdown<DocumentType>(
          //   items: DocumentType.values
          //       .map(
          //         (docType) => DropdownItem(
          //           value: docType,
          //           label: docType.name,
          //         ),
          //       )
          //       .toList(),
          //   onSelectionChange: (value) {
          //     setState(() {
          //       _selectedDocumentType = value.first;
          //     });
          //   },
          // ),
          if (_selectedDocumentType != null)
            Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                FilledButton(
                  style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      fixedSize: const Size(420, 40),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
                  onPressed: () {
                    //   final response = Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/submit');
                    setState(() {
                      _fileUploaded = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("Enviar Documento"),
                      Icon(Icons.upload_file),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          if (_fileUploaded)
            Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                TextField(
                  controller: _dataController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Data de Vencimento",
                    suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
                  ),
                  onTap: () async {
                    final DateTime? selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
                      context: context,
                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
                      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                    );
                    if (selectedDate != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        _dataController.text =
                            "${selectedDate.day}/${selectedDate.month}/${selectedDate.year}";
                        _selectedDate = selectedDate;
                        _dateSelected = true;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          if (_dateSelected)
            Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                FilledButton(
                  style: FilledButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: STDColors.green,
                      fixedSize: const Size(420, 40),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: const Text(
                    "Enviar",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
        ],
      ).withPadding(
        const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubmittDocumentPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SubmittDocumentPage({super.key, required this.documentType});

  final DocumentType documentType;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Placeholder();
  }
}

So then, I tried to combine the codes, but it didnt work, the dropdown error happened again.
